# kubernetes cannot make http requests between clusters

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

here's the situation :
we have 2 clusters A & B,  when trying to make an http request from cluster A (Job) to a service in Cluster B (using public https address) i don't get any response (time out) !
I'm new to kuberenetes So I would like to know the best way or maybe an easy fix to this Situation

Kuberenetes v1.21

**Kube-proxy logs**

```
E0816 08:12:49.069369       1 utils.go:282] Skipping invalid IP: 
E0816 08:12:49.069388       1 utils.go:282] Skipping invalid IP: 
E0816 08:12:49.069394       1 utils.go:282] Skipping invalid IP: 
E0816 08:12:49.069402       1 utils.go:282] Skipping invalid IP: 
I0816 08:14:38.828143       1 proxier.go:854] "Syncing iptables rules"
I0816 08:14:38.849024       1 proxier.go:824] "syncProxyRules complete" elapsed="20.89552ms"
W0816 08:17:21.911048       1 warnings.go:70] discovery.k8s.io/v1beta1 EndpointSlice is deprecated in v1.21+, unavailable in v1.25+; use discovery.k8s.io/v1 EndpointSlice
I0816 08:18:06.618311       1 proxier.go:854] "Syncing iptables rules"
I0816 08:18:06.646124       1 proxier.go:824] "syncProxyRules complete" elapsed="27.861586ms"
W0816 08:23:46.915519       1 warnings.go:70] discovery.k8s.io/v1beta1 EndpointSlice is deprecated in v1.21+, unavailable in v1.25+; use discovery.k8s.io/v1 EndpointSlice
E0816 08:27:49.069409       1 utils.go:282] Skipping invalid IP: 
E0816 08:27:49.069429       1 utils.go:282] Skipping invalid IP: 
E0816 08:27:49.069436       1 utils.go:282] Skipping invalid IP: 
E0816 08:27:49.069443       1 utils.go:282] Skipping invalid IP: 
W0816 08:31:08.919514       1 warnings.go:70] discovery.k8s.io/v1beta1 EndpointSlice is deprecated in v1.21+, unavailable in v1.25+; use discovery.k8s.io/v1 EndpointSlice
W0816 08:36:43.923978       1 warnings.go:70] discovery.k8s.io/v1beta1 EndpointSlice is deprecated in v1.21+, unavailable in v1.25+; use discovery.k8s.io/v1 EndpointSlice
```

Comment: can you please improve your question with additional resources such as logs from kube-proxy, what networking solution you are using, what distribution of k8s you are using. The more information we have, the better will be the answer

Comment: Yes,add k get events.

Comment: no events found

Comment: what does kubectl config view(cluster B) show?